# How to check if a number is included in a range (in one statement)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, numbers, range

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to check if a number is included in a range. That is, if I have a variable `number = 5` I would like to check `1 <= number <= 10` and retrieve a boolean value if the `number` value is included in that range.

I can do that like this:

```
number >= 1 && number <= 10
```

but I would like to do that in one statement. How can I do that?

Comment: Since there's nothing wrong with your cited statement it begs the question: why do want/need to further "shorten" it ?

Comment: @DarkDust - Less code as well as possible!

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`(1..10).include?(number)` is the trick.

Btw: If you want to validate a number using `ActiveModel::Validations`, you can even do:

```
validates_inclusion_of :number, :in => 1..10
```

read [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of) about validates_inclusion_of

or the Rails 3+ way:

```
validates :number, :inclusion => 1..10
```

Comment: What if I want also to allow nil? I'm getting an error when it's nil.

Comment: Rails has a option `allow_nil`. Just add it like so: `, allow_nil: true`

Answer (score 78):

[Enumerable#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
(1..10).include? n
```

[Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

```
(1..10).cover? n
```

[Comparable#between?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
n.between? 1, 10
```

[Numericality Validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality):

```
validates :n, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 10}
```

[Inclusion Validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion):

```
validates :n, inclusion: 1..10
```

Comment: I like this method better, because the validation text makes more sense.

Comment: I like it better because I was already validation numericality. Makes it a one-line :)

Comment: @BradGreens that's one long line.

Comment: I want to note that u can use proc if u need some specific logic or access to associations. For example `validates :amount, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: ->(m) { m.user.balance }, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }`

Answer (score 17):

If it's not part of a validation process you can use `#between?` :

```
2.between?(1, 4)
=> true
```

Answer (score 9):

For accurate error messages on a form submit , try these

```
validates_numericality_of :tax_rate, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100, message: 'must be between 0 & 100'
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4

> if you want it through ActiveModel::Validations you can use

```
validates_inclusion_of :number, :in => start_number..end_number
```

> or the Rails 3 syntax

```
validates :number, :inclusion => start_number..end_number
```

But The simplest way i find is

`number.between? start_number, end_number`

Comment: Perhaps include some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9 the most direct translation seems to be [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

> Returns true if obj is between beg and end, i.e beg <= obj <= end (or
>   end exclusive when exclude_end? is true).

In case you wonder how that's different from `Range#include?`, it's that the latter iterates over all elements of the range if it's a non-numeric range. See this [blog post](http://rhnh.net/2009/08/03/range-include-in-ruby-1-9) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check particular number exists in custom array,

As for example I want to know whether 5 is included in list=[1,4,6,10] or not

```
list.include? 5 => false
list.include? 6 => true
```